# How to connect to Mongo db server remotely through its default ports?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a mongo db server remotely through the default port to view the db contents. Suggest me how to do that remotely , it could also be either through python or node.js.

Comment: Did you try to connect using connection String?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide code and error message.

Answer (score 1):

To  connect remotely to a  mongodb server, then all you will need is :
*. database URI
Which comprises of **database name** and **authentication if needed**

Sample code for connecting to remote mongodb shared atlas cluster is like this:

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 var cors = require('cors')
 const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

 const uri = 'mongodb+srv://xxx-sampledb:xxx-mongodb- 
              sampledb@sandbox.xxxx.mongodb.net/ellasShop?authSource=admin';


 //middleware 
 app.use(express.json())
 app.use(cors())

 //initialize db connectivity options
 const options = {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
 }


app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
   const client = new MongoClient(uri, options);

    try {
       await client.connect();

       const database = client.db('ellasShop')
       const collection = database.collection('productData')
       const products = await collection.findOne();
       return res.json(products);
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
   } finally{
      await client.close()
   }
 })

 app.listen(5000, () => {
       console.log('Server is running')
 })
```

[image: database on shared atlas cluster]
[image: retrieve records from remote database access on localhost]